# jquery: handle 2 submit buttons in A form without refresh the whole page

Tags: php, jquery

I'm building a form with 2 submit buttons, one is 'Save', the another is 'Delete'. After select a value and click Save, everything is still normal, but when click Delete button and then again click Save button, the Save button now work as 'Delete' button. Notice that I'm using JQuery to process data in the whole form in order not to refresh the whole page.

Here is the HTML form:

```
    <div id="reload"> // using to reload this part after submit a form
    <!-- Select Item -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="itemID">Select menu item: </label>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <select id="itemID" name="itemID" class="form-control" onchange="select_menu()">

                    <option value="0">--No selection--</option>
                    {{$data}}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Name input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="menuName">Menu name: </label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="menuName" name="menuName" type="text" placeholder="(max 50 char)"
                       class="form-control input-md" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Link input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="link">Link URL: </label>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="link" name="link" type="text" placeholder="link URL"
                       class="form-control input-md">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Select Parent -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="parentID">Parent name: </label>

            <div class="col-md-5">
                <select id="parentID" name="parentID" class="form-control">
                    <option value="0">--No parent--</option>
                    {{$data}}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</div> // end div 'reload'

        <!-- Save Button -->
                <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="editmenu">Save changes
                </button>

        <!-- Delete Button -->
                <button type="submit" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger" formaction="deletemenu">Delete
                    item
                </button>
Here is the Jquery process part:

    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
        var c = confirm("Are you sure?");
        if (c == true) {
            $('#editMenu').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var editMenu = $('#editMenu').serializeArray();
                var url = $('#btnSave').attr('formaction');

                $.post(url, editMenu, function (data) {
                    if (data == 'fail') {
                        $('#fdk').show().addClass('alert alert-danger').fadeIn(2000);
                        $('#msg').text('Duplicate name');
                    }
                    if (data == 'pass') {
                        $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
                            options.async = true;
                        });
                        $("#reload").load(document.URL + " #reload");
                        $('#fdk').show().addClass('alert alert-success').fadeIn(2000);
                        $('#msg').text('Changes saved');
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        else if (c == false) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    //    function delete_function() {
    $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
        var c = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item and all its children?");
        if (c == true) {
            $('#editMenu').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var editMenu = $('#editMenu').serializeArray();
                var url = $('#btnDelete').attr('formaction');

                $.post(url, editMenu, function (data) {
                    if (data == 'fail') {
                        $('#fdk').show().addClass('alert alert-danger').fadeIn(2000);
                        $('#msg').text('Cannot delete. Try again later');
                    }
                    if (data == 'pass') {
                        $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
                            options.async = true;
                        });
//reload a div part.
                        $("#reload").load(document.URL + " #reload");
//sucessfully message
                        $('#fdk').show().addClass('alert alert-success').fadeIn(2000);
                        $('#msg').text('Successfully deleted');
                    }
                });
            });
        } else if (c == false) {
            return false;
        }
    });
</script>
```